# Is $S = I + T^\dagger T$ surjective?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

***The Question:***  Let $H$ be a (real or complex) Hilbert space, and let $T \in \mathscr L(H)$ be a bounded, and hence continuous, linear operator on $H$.  Consider the operator $S = I + T^\dagger T \in \mathscr L(H)$; we know that $S:  H \to S(H)$ is injective, that it has a continuous inverse on $S(H)$, and that $S(H)$ is closed in $H$, these things are all established in the [answers to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478841/show-that-s-1sh-to-h-exist-where-is-h-is-hilbert-space-and-t-is).  Here I ask:  is $S = I + T^\dagger T$ *surjective*?

***Background and Motivation:***  It is with great relief I affirm that my days of homework appear to be long past.  I ask this question because it, albeit indirectly, bears upon my research on neural networks, and also out of pure mathematical interest.  I often encounter operators of the form $I + T^\dagger T$, and have in fact been curious about this question for quite some time.  I have cast about on the web, and searched a bit on this site, but nothing obvious popped up.

***What I Tried:***  I made *some* progress by imposing further hypotheses on $T$; the case of $T^\dagger T$ compact is answered affirmatively in the linked citing given above.  My approaches have all been based on the fact that $T^\dagger T$ is self-adjoint and positive semi-definite, and to go from there to finding if possible some spectral representation of $T^\dagger T$ which presents an orthonormal basis of $H$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T^\dagger T$, and from there to constructing solutions to $Sz = y$ in a manner to analogous to equation (13) of the post linked above.  But I have not as yet succeeded.

Specific items of interest:

***1.)***  Does it make any difference if $H$ is a real or complex Hilbert space?

***2.)***  What additional conditions may be placed upon $T$ or $T^\dagger T$ to establish that $I + T^\dagger T$ is surjective?

***3.)***  Counterexamples or more than welcome.

***4.)***  Demonstrations which rely as little as possible on spectral theory will be ***most*** welcome.

I've probably typed enough.  Thanks for your attention to this query.

Comment: What is $T^\dagger?$

Comment: @TheoBendit:  $T^\dagger$ is the Hermitian adjoint of $T$; $\langle T^\dagger x, y \rangle = \langle x, Ty \rangle$ for all $x, y \in H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually true, given any positive semi-definite transformation $T$, that $T + I$ is invertible. The spectrum of a positive semi-definite transformation consists only of non-negative real numers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element

This means that $-1$ is not in the spectrum, so by definition $T - (-1)I$ is invertible.

Comment: This looks great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $A$ is a self adjoint bounded operator, then 
$\operatorname{ker}(A)$ is the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{range}(A)$, because $y$ is perpendicular to $\operatorname{range}(A)$,  if and only if for all $x$, $0 = \langle A x, y\rangle = \langle x, A y\rangle$, if and only if $A y = 0$.  Thus if $A$ is injective, then it has dense range.   Apply this to your operator
$I + T^* T$. It is injective with closed range.  But since it is injective, it has dense range. Hence it is surjective.

Comment: Looks really nice; the kind of answer I seek.  Thanks!